# Python: How to find the indices of the first and last character in a consecutive series

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have string = "aaabaa"

Using this information, I would like to find the indices of the first and last 'a' 's

Edit: sorry for being ambiguous: the longest consecutive string of 'a' 's is aaa, so I would like to find the indices 0 and 2, instead of 0 and 5.

I'm able to find the length of the longest number of a's, using code from Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's response here: [Counting longest occurrence of repeated sequence in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664150/counting-longest-occurrence-of-repeated-sequence-in-python)

Comment: _"find the indices of the first and last 'a' 's"_ Would that be 0 and 5 or 0 and 2?

Comment: Answer that kind of questions isn't the intent of stack overflow, please read the [how to make good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should be more specific of what part you do not understand or cannot figure out yourself. In this way others who do wonder the same thing will easier find the answers, to the part you do not understand, more useful.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is simple way to find longest series of consecutive c in string s:

```
def find_consecutive(s, c):
    len = 0
    len_list = []
    for x in s:
        if x == c:
            if len==0:
                len = 1
            else:
                len  += 1
        else:
            len_list.append(len)
            len = 0
    return max(len_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Index of first a:

```
myString.find('a')
```

Index of last a:

```
myString.rfind('a')
```

Length of the longest series of consecutive a's:

```
counter = 0
maxCount = 0
for c in myString:
    if c == 'a':
        counter+=1
        if counter > maxCount:
            maxCount = counter
    else:
        counter = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the neat code. How would I go about finding the last a in the first set of a's (they're the longest consecutive string of a's). Also, would the a in find() be 'a'?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice function for you. And I think that you wanted to know where the starting index and the ending index is for the longest occurrence of a's.

```
def find_longest_a(string):

    start_index = 0
    current_index = 0
    end_index = 0
    count_a = 0

    max_a = 0
    max_a_start_index = 0
    max_a_end_index = 0

    for character in string:
        if character == 'a':
            count_a += 1
            end_index = current_index

        elif character != 'a':
            if count_a > max_a:
                max_a = count_a
                max_a_start_index = start_index
                max_a_end_index = end_index

            start_index = current_index + 1
            count_a = 0

        current_index += 1

    if count_a > max_a:
        max_a = count_a
        max_a_start_index = start_index
        max_a_end_index = end_index

    return max_a, max_a_start_index, max_a_end_index
```

if you run this function:

```
>>> find_longest_a("aabs?1jlkdaklaa aa a aaaasnd a")
```

it will return this:

```
(4, 21, 24)
```

4 is the number of a's, 21 is the index where the this sequence starts and 24 is where this sequence ends.

Comment: This code works great, except when the longest string of 'a' 's is at the end of the string. I reckon this is due to an issue with not updating the max_a, max_a_start_index ... etc. For instance, the string 'abaa' outputs incorrectly

Comment: Hello @JeremyFeng, I added an if statement after the for-loop, now it should work if the longest a's is at the end :)

Answer (score 1):

So here is what I came up with. Not doing anything fancy so the steps can be pretty clear. I first look for the first appearance of the character we are searching for. When it is found, `i` is the start index . then i keep looping through string until i find a character that is not the one we want. When i find one it means the end index is `current index - 1`. I append these values to a start list and end list. then i reset the values and keep going. This way I can get multiple consecutive sets of repeated strings.

at the end i use `zip()` to create tuples of start and end indices.

```
def find_indices(str, toFind):
    found = False #tells us if what we are searching for is found
    start = [] #holds start inds
    end = [] #hold end inds
    i = 0   #tracks index
    for letter in str:
        if letter == toFind: #found the letter
            if found == False:
                found = True
                start.append(i) #first index
        if letter != toFind and found == True: #found the character after the last character we wanted
            end.append(i - 1) #we are at the character after the we want so index - 1
            found = False #not found anymore so so found is false
        i += 1

    #handles the case where the last letter is one we care about since the for loop is looking for char
    #after the one we want and in this case the one we want is last. 
    if str[-1:] == toFind:
        end.append(len(str)-1)

    #combine the starts and end into tuples of starts and ends. 
    return zip(start, end)
```

if you run this function you get:

`(Pdb) inds = find_indices('aaabaa', 'a')`

`(Pdb) inds  '

`[(0, 2), (4, 5)]`

Using a bigger string:

```
x = 'aaabaakjhasdfaaaaaaaakjhasdfasdgoaaaalkjadslkjgoa aa lkahjga;lskdhgalskhdgaaaaa'
(Pdb) inds  = find_indicies(x, 'a')
(Pdb) inds
[(0, 2), (4, 5), (9, 9), (13, 20), (24, 24), (28, 28), (33, 36), (40, 40), (48, 48), (50, 51), (55, 55), (59, 59), (67, 67), (74, 78)]
```